# Running Windows and macOS simultaneously on two screens

Tags: windows

Is it possible to run Windows (on an external SSD drive) and macOS simultaneously on two screens?

I want to use macOS on my MacBook and, at the same time, Windows installed on an external SSD drive and connected to an external screen.

Answer (score 2):

[Parallels for Mac](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) or [VMware Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html). Both would allow you to run Windows on top of macOS.

Comment: But parallels gives me an opportunity to install Windows on external drive or not?

Comment: Not technically install, but you can place the virtual machine file on an external drive.

Comment: VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org) is a third option. VMs can also be installed on an external drive.

Comment: VMWare have a free for personal use version of Fusion.